# Nested For not working in Async Function - React Native App

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function which I get some data from database and I want to create a structured JSON object and pass it to an API.
I can get the data from database and create an JSON object, but for some reason the FOR loop is only running after all the routine. I've already spent sometime trying to solve this, but I couldn't. If someone could help me, it would be really appreciated.

This is the full function:

```
async function SendFullAudit() {
//Method to call from API
console.log('INSIDE SEND FULL AUDIT');    
var auditHeader = { AUDITHEADER: {}, AUDITITEMS: {} };   
var auditItemToSend = { PICTURES: {} };
var ItemstoAdd = []; 
var Picture = {
  content: {},
};
db.transaction(async(tx) => 
{
  console.log('Get audits results' + auditsTosend[0].ID);
  tx.executeSql('select id, audit_item_id,od,comments,status_id,scanned_code,findings from tb_audits where audit_id = ? ', [auditsTosend[0].ID], (tx, results) => {        
    for (let i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
      tx.executeSql('select AUDIT_ID,PICTURE_URI from tb_AuditPictures where audit_ID =?', [results.rows.item(i).ID], async (tx, resultsPic) => {
        console.log('Pictures Result inside full audit:' + resultsPic.rows.length + ' for item:' + results.rows.item(i).ID);
        if (resultsPic.rows.length > 0) {
          for (let j = 0; j < resultsPic.rows.length; j++) {
              var tempPic = resultsPic.rows.item(j);
              console.log('Inside resultsPic.rows.length > 0' + tempPic.PICTURE_URI);                
              auditPictures = await RNFS.readFile(tempPic.PICTURE_URI, 'base64').then(res => {
              Picture.content = res;
              ItemstoAdd[i].PICTURES = Picture;
              console.log("ItemstoAdd:" + ItemstoAdd[i].ID + " ITEM PICTURE:" + Picture.content);
            });
            
          }
        }            
      });          
      auditItemToSend = results.rows.item(i);
      ItemstoAdd.push(auditItemToSend);
    }        
    auditHeader.AUDITHEADER = auditsTosend;
    auditHeader.AUDITITEMS = ItemstoAdd;
    console.log('\n');        
    console.log('stringFy headerItem:' + JSON.stringify(auditHeader));
  });
});  }
```

When the routine runs, the first console shown is this **console.log('Get audits results' + auditsTosend[0].ID);** , followed by this **console.log('stringFy headerItem:' + JSON.stringify(auditHeader));** which is after the FOR loop, and at this moment the auditHeader doesn't have the Pictures yet.
After that it runs the FOR loop, how could I get auditHeader var with the the Pictures which is added inside the for loop?

I've spent a lot of time with this problem, and read a lot about promises.
Now the query is using a join with the URI from database, and inside the function I'm calling a for loop which converts the URI into a base64, using react-native-fs. But the ReadFile function only returns after the main function. How could I make the GetFullAuditData await the ReadFile functions end?

```
    async function ReadFile(PICTURE_URI)
  {      
      let data = await RNFS.readFile(PICTURE_URI, 'base64').then(res=>{ return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {resolve(res),reject((err)=>console.log("Error:"+err))})});
      data = String(data);
      //base64Pict.push("PIC:"+data);
      console.log("ReadFile:"+data);
  } 

    function GetFullAuditData()
{
  //var auditHeader = auditsTosend;
  var auditHeader = { AUDITHEADER: {}, AUDITITEMS: {PICTURES: {content: {}}}  };
  var auditItemToSend = { PICTURES: {} };
  var ItemstoAdd = [];
  var Picture = {content: {}};

  console.log('GET FULL AUDIT');
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  {
    console.log('CREATE PROMISE');
     db.transaction(async(tx) => {
       // tx.executeSql('select id, audit_item_id,od,comments,status_id,scanned_code,findings,"" as PICTURES from tb_audits where audit_id = ? ', [auditsTosend[0].ID], (tx, results) => {
        tx.executeSql('select a.id, a.audit_item_id,a.od,a.comments,a.status_id,a.scanned_code,a.findings,ap.PICTURE_URI, "" AS PIC64 from tb_audits a left join tb_AuditPictures ap on a.ID = ap.AUDIT_ID where a.AUDIT_ID = ? ', [auditsTosend[0].ID], (tx, results) => {
            console.log("Query completed");
            var len = results.rows.length;
            var items =[];
            for (let i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
               let row = results.rows.item(i);
               console.log('RESULTS LENGTH:'+row.PICTURE_URI)
               if (row.PICTURE_URI!=null)
               {
                var PIC64 = ReadFile(row.PICTURE_URI);//ReturnPicture64(row.PICTURE_URI);
                console.log('PIC64:'+ PIC64);
               }
               items.push(results.rows.item(i));
               console.log('Record:'+ row.PIC64);
            }
            resolve(items)
            reject((err)=>console.log("ERROR:"+err))

        });
    });
});
}
```

Comment: This question can be closed, I've solved the situation using another way. Instead of use nested FOR loop, I've brought all the data from the database and the stringfy the result to JSON and then send to the API

Answer (score 0):

Your code suffers from the callback hell issue. You know, async callbacks that you are passing don't await! It will help if you handle them manually by converting callbacks to Promises.

```js
async function SendFullAudit() {
//Method to call from API
  console.log('INSIDE SEND FULL AUDIT');
  var auditHeader = { AUDITHEADER: {}, AUDITITEMS: {} };
  var auditItemToSend = { PICTURES: {} };
  var ItemstoAdd = [];
  var Picture = {
    content: {},
  };
  db.transaction(async(tx) =>
  {
    console.log('Get audits results' + auditsTosend[0].ID);
    const {tx, results} = await new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      tx.executeSql('select id, audit_item_id,od,comments,status_id,scanned_code,findings from tb_audits where audit_id = ? ', [auditsTosend[0].ID], (tx, results) => {
        resolve({tx, results})
      })      
    })
    // tx.executeSql('select id, audit_item_id,od,comments,status_id,scanned_code,findings from tb_audits where audit_id = ? ', [auditsTosend[0].ID], (tx, results) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
        const {tx, resultsPic} = await new Promise((resolve)=>{
          tx.executeSql('select AUDIT_ID,PICTURE_URI from tb_AuditPictures where audit_ID =?', [results.rows.item(i).ID], (tx, resultsPic) => {
            resolve({tx, resultsPic})
          })
        })
        // tx.executeSql('select AUDIT_ID,PICTURE_URI from tb_AuditPictures where audit_ID =?', [results.rows.item(i).ID], async (tx, resultsPic) => {
          console.log('Pictures Result inside full audit:' + resultsPic.rows.length + ' for item:' + results.rows.item(i).ID);
          if (resultsPic.rows.length > 0) {
            for (let j = 0; j < resultsPic.rows.length; j++) {
              var tempPic = resultsPic.rows.item(j);
              console.log('Inside resultsPic.rows.length > 0' + tempPic.PICTURE_URI);
              auditPictures = await RNFS.readFile(tempPic.PICTURE_URI, 'base64').then(res => {
                Picture.content = res;
                ItemstoAdd[i].PICTURES = Picture;
                console.log("ItemstoAdd:" + ItemstoAdd[i].ID + " ITEM PICTURE:" + Picture.content);
              });

            }
          }
        // });
        auditItemToSend = results.rows.item(i);
        ItemstoAdd.push(auditItemToSend);
      }
      auditHeader.AUDITHEADER = auditsTosend;
      auditHeader.AUDITITEMS = ItemstoAdd;
      console.log('\n');
      console.log('stringFy headerItem:' + JSON.stringify(auditHeader));
    // });
  }); 
 }
```

To be honest, there is no easy way to try your code out to testify the result. I've tried my best to show the way. Hope it would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll try your suggestion and post it back here.